# How can I write the pattern correctly in string.gmatch?

Tags: lua

I wrote some code like this:

```
        local word = "<color=#FF0000>123</color>asdf<color=#00FF00>456</color>"
        local list = {}
        for match in string.gmatch(word, "<color=#%w+>.+</color>") do
            print(match)
        end
```

But the output was the total word **"<color=#FF0000>123<//color>asdf<color=#00FF00>456<//color>"**,

But what I want is **"<color=#FF0000>123<//color>"** and **"<color=#00FF00>456<//color>"**,

How can I get the matches I want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that doesn't work in Lua. `?` may only be used for single optional characters in patterns. Lua patterns aren't RegEx. The "lazy" quantifier is `-`.

Comment: You should [not parse HTML with RegEx (or patterns)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7185318)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.+` to  `.-`.

`+` find longest sequence.
`-` find shortest sequence.